# Minimum three months between created case numbers for unique policy numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with three columns, policy_no, casenumber, created_date; multiple different case numbers can be created for the same unique policy no. I need to pull through all the data from the table except where there is less than three months gap between the latest created case number and any created before that. So, for instance, where a case number has been created for a policy number on 1st July, but there were also case numbers created before that for the same policy number on 15th June and 1st May, I only want to pull through data for the case number that was created on 1st July, because I only want to count that unique policy number once. When the gap is greater than three months however, for instance, when a case number was created 1st July, and the last one created before that was created on 30th April, then I want to include both those cases and have a count of 2 for that unique policy number.

I hope all this makes sense! Not sure where to begin with this one!

Comment: But what if dates are like 1 Jul, 1 May and 1 Mar? Gaps are 2 months, but gap between last and first is 4 months. Answer depends on if You want two or one row in this case.

Comment: Hi, only the case raised on 1 mar should be included. basically, whenever a case is raised within 90 days of the last, it should replace that in the query. So only the latest case, plus any for which no further case was raised within the following 90 days is included. If after the 1st Mar no further case was raised until 30/05/2019, the cases raised on 1st mar would be 'banked', and always now included in the query, the case raised on 30/05/2019 would also be included (unless another case was raised within 90 days, and that would be included).

Answer (score 1):

First, you should be aware that [month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Month) is not a precise unit of time. Here I used Oracle function `months_between`, but you can also substract dates and compare with 30. `Months_between` may give results which are not intuitive but they are correct. For instance:

```
select months_between(date '2019-03-29', date '2019-02-28') from dual;

select months_between(date '2019-03-31', date '2019-02-28') from dual;
```

First select gives `1.03`, second gives `1`. Strange but logical. It is because month is not precise unit.

You are warned :) Now solution. First my sample data, 3 distinct policy numbers with different cases:

```
create table policies(policy_no, casenumber, created_date) as (
    select 1, 101, date '2007-01-01' from dual union all
    select 1, 102, date '2007-02-01' from dual union all
    select 1, 103, date '2007-06-01' from dual union all
    select 1, 104, date '2007-09-15' from dual union all
    select 1, 105, date '2007-11-01' from dual union all    
    select 1, 106, date '2007-12-01' from dual union all
    select 2, 201, date '1992-08-30' from dual union all
    select 3, 301, date '1995-07-12' from dual union all
    select 3, 302, date '1995-08-30' from dual union all
    select 3, 303, date '1997-02-25' from dual );
```

And my query:

```
with 
    t(pn, cn, cdt, rn) as (
      select policy_no, casenumber, created_date, 
             row_number() over (partition by policy_no order by created_date desc) 
        from policies),
    c(pn, cn, cdt, rn, diff, ldt, info) as (
      select pn, cn, cdt, 1, 0, cdt,  'last' from t where rn = 1
      union all 
      select t.pn, t.cn, t.cdt, t.rn, round(months_between(c.ldt, t.cdt), 2),
             case when months_between(c.ldt, t.cdt) >= 3 then t.cdt else c.ldt end,
             case when months_between(c.ldt, t.cdt) >= 3 then 'inlcuded' else 'excluded' end
        from c join t on t.pn = c.pn and t.rn = c.rn + 1)
select * from c order by pn, rn
```

Result:

```
        PN         CN CDT                 RN       DIFF LDT         INFO
---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- --------
         1        106 2007-12-01           1          0 2007-12-01  last
         1        105 2007-11-01           2          1 2007-12-01  excluded
         1        104 2007-09-15           3       2,55 2007-12-01  excluded
         1        103 2007-06-01           4          6 2007-06-01  inlcuded
         1        102 2007-02-01           5          4 2007-02-01  inlcuded
         1        101 2007-01-01           6          1 2007-02-01  excluded
         2        201 1992-08-30           1          0 1992-08-30  last
         3        303 1997-02-25           1          0 1997-02-25  last
         3        302 1995-08-30           2      17,84 1995-08-30  inlcuded
         3        301 1995-07-12           3       1,58 1995-08-30  excluded
```

You are interested only in rows with info `last` or `included`.

How does it work? Subquery `t` only adds numbering to rows, it is for each policy sepearated, newest case is first. Subquery `c` is the main part of the solution. 
It is recursive. We start with row numbers `1` and in each next step we look for next row number and check if its date is older than three months from remembered. 
If it is we save it (in column ldt), if no, the previous is used.

This is how recursive query works. I hope I understood correctly. If you need to check only between neighbouring rows then function `lag` or `lead` would be enough, but here you need recursion.

Hope this helps and sorry for any language mistakes :)

Comment: Thank you so very much, I'm going to take this evening to work through and fully understand what you've done. It looks awesome work to me. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, it's so close. Here's where it can snag. I have an example of a policy which had cases logged on the following dates;                                                                                              
16-APR-19 (last)
22-JAN-19 (exc)
14-MAY-18 (inc)
14-MAR-18 (exc)
29-DEC-17 (inc)
05-SEP-17 (inc)
22-AUG-17 (exc)
19-JUL-17 (exc)
04-JUL-17 (exc)
12-MAY-17 (inc)
10-MAY-17 (exc)
13-DEC-16 (inc)
The case on the 12-MAY-17 gets included, though another was raised on 4/07/2017. Can the code be even better? if not, I'll take what you've written and be very grateful.

Comment: But 04-JUL-17 is excluded (because previous banked was 05-SEP-17). So 12-MAY-17 gets included. Please look at this [dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1676efb74809868bc8224eb3718ebf09) with the exact dates you mentioned. It shows in each row last banked date and difference in months, which is the reason why checked date is included or excluded.

Comment: It's almost working beautifully, but it needs to calculate the gap between a case's created date and the next case created after it. So the difference between the case created 12-MAY-17 and the next one 04-JUL-17 is 1.74 and therefore the 12-MAY-17 case should be excluded, but the difference between the cases created on 05-Sep-17 and the next one 29-dec-17 is 3.4 and so the 05-sep-17 case should be banked and included. Hope is all is clear, very sorry to such a pain!

Answer (score 0):

the below query will give u record for came policy cases wich are more than 3 months apart. 90 days.

```
SELECT A.POLICY_NO,
       A.CASENUMBER,
       A.CREATED_DATE,
       B.CASENUMBER,
       B.CREATED_DATE
  FROM POLICY_CASES A, POLICY_CASES B
 WHERE     A.POLICY_NO = B.A.POLICY_NO
       AND A.CASENUMBER <> B.CASENUMBER
       AND B.CREATED_DATE > A.CREATED_DATE
       AND (B.CREATED_DATE - A.CREATED_DATE) > 90
       order by 1,3,5
```

some more data is required like if raised case is already solved. to include that or only include pending cases. or you want only latest  and second last etc.

Comment: Hi, basically whenever three months lapse, the cycle would begin again. So if a case was raised on a policy on 01/01/2019, 15/01/2019, 24/02/2019, 25/05/2019,31//05/2019, 30/06/2019 and 28/09/2019 the cases which should be included in the query are the ones raised on 24/02/2019, 30/06/2019 and 28/09/2019. So the latest is always included, plus any where no additional case was raised within the next 90 days. If another case was subsequently raised on 30/09/2019, this would replace the case raised on on 28/09/2019, as that should no longer be included. Hope all this makes sense!